# When does a limit of a sequence equal both its lim sup and lim inf?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Suppose $(a_n)_{n\ge1}$ is a positive (so non-zero), real sequence with $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=L$, where $L\in[0,\infty]$. Is this equivalent with $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=L$? In particular, does this hold for the infinity case? If so, why? Thank you!

Comment: In the case of infinity it doesn’t hold https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior (under properties)

Comment: I think that it *does* hold for infinity, actually, by the definition of divergence to infinity.

Comment: @gbox I don't see directly what you mean. Could you be more precise about the position of this fact in the page of the link you posted, or elaborate what you mean in an answer?

Comment: If $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = \infty$, then for all $M > 0$, there is an $n_M\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n\geq M$ for all $n\geq n_M$. Letting $y_m := \inf_{n\geq m} x_n$, we have that for $M\geq 0$, $y_m\geq M$ for all $m\geq n_M$ due to the fact that $y_m$ is increasing in $m$. Therefore, $y_m\to \infty$ as $m\to \infty$. By the fact that $z_m := \sup_{n\geq m} x_n$ dominates $y_m$, we also have $z_m\to \infty$.

Comment: @Tyron it's incorrect and therefore won't appear on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: @MichaelL. Im not sure how you have disproven the infinite case... that seems to be precisely the description needed to prove the infinite case. Where is the disproof?  If both liminf and limsup tend to infinity then why wouldnt lim?  Also, just because wikipeida doesnt include it doesnt mean it isnt true; in fact many of the things wikipeida does say are false (just take a look at their political propaganda pages). Wiki is one of the least reliable sites on the internet and doesnt constitute a valid citation by any measure.

Comment: My point was to prove the infinite case, not to disprove it. The previous commenter linking Wikipedia was incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The $\displaystyle\liminf_{n \to +\infty} a_n$ denotes the smallest adherence value of the sequence $(a_n)_n$. The $\displaystyle\limsup_{n \to +\infty} a_n$ denotes the greatest adherence value of the sequence $(a_n)_n$. Recall that $\ell$ is an adherence value of $(a_n)_n$ if there is a subsequence of $(a_n)_n$ which converges to $\ell$. Thus, if the limit inf is equal to the limit sup then the whole series converges to this common limit. The reverse is also true.

Comment: Thank you. Can the same reasoning be applied to the case in which $L=\infty$, with $L$ as in my question?

Comment: In my answer, $\ell$ can be a real number or $\pm \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

It is equivalent. If $\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n = \liminf_{n \to \infty} a_n = L \in \mathbb{R}$, then the set of partial limits will only contain $L$ (If it contains anything else: say bigger than $L$: then L is not the supremum of the set, and similarly for the other cases). Now, if $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \neq L$, then there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ s.t. for any $N$ there exists $k > N$ s.t. $|a_k - L| \geq \varepsilon$. The sequence $a_k$ (formalization needed here) contains a sequence that converges to a real number or plusminus infinity (any sequence does), and it cannot converge L (since $|a_k - L| \geq \varepsilon$), denoted by $K$. Then $K\neq L$ but K is a partial sum. Contradiction! Therefore $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$.

The other direction is clear: if a sequence is convergent, any of its subsequence will converge with her, and therefore the set of partial limits will contain its limit only.

I trust you to fill in the $+-\infty$ case :)

Comment: In fact, I also know how to prove the first case. Can you please elaborate on the infinity cases? Do not trust me, I got lost.